# Add min char and a way to find words with first letter capitalized to a regex

Tags: php, regex

Hi guys have the following regex:

```
/([A-Z][\w-]*(\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+)/
```

I've tried in different way, but i'm not a pro with regex..so, this is what want to do:

1. Add a rule that match only 3+ characters words.
2. Add a rule that can match name like "Institute of Technology" (so, three words with a lowercase word between the first and the last)

Can you help me to do that? (I should do different regex, am i right?)

Comment: `of` is not `3+ characters word`

Comment: okay, i think i should do more than one regex so, anyway..i need a way to detect string like "Institute of Technology"

Comment: /[A_Z]\w+\s+[a-z]+\s[A-Z]\w+/` or change `\w` with `[a-z]`

Comment: thank you so much, it work..and if i want to detect all word with first capital and with at least 3 char?

Comment: `[A-Z][a-z]{2,}`

Comment: i made a typo there - `/[A-Z]\w+\s+[a-z]+\s[A-Z]\w+/``

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you to understand, this is what you have:

- `[A-Z]`: one character in the class A-Z
- `[\w-]*`: a concatenation of zero or more word character or hypens
- `(...)+`: one or more:

  - `\s+`: at least one space
  - `[A-Z]`: one character in the class A-Z
  - `[\w-]*`: a concatenation of zero or more word character or hypens

This is what you want:

- `[A-Z]`: a capital letter
- `[\w-]*`: a concatenation of zero or more word character or hypens
- `\s+`: at least one space
- `[a-z]`: a lower-case letter
- `[\w-]*`: a concatenation of zero or more word character or hypens
- `\s+`: at least one space
- `[A-Z]`: a capital letter
- `[\w-]*`: a concatenation of zero or more word character or hypens

That is:

```
[A-Z][\w-]*\s+[a-z][\w-]*\s+[A-Z][\w-]*
```

You may want to do some small changes. I think you can do them by your own.

---

A rule that matches only 3+ characters word is `\w{3,}`. If you want to capitalize the first character use `[A-Z]\w{2,}`.

Answer (score 0):

`(\w\w\w+)|(\w+ [a-z]+ \w+)`  - This code searches for a word consisting of at least 3 letters OR a word with at least 1 sign, space, small letters, 1+ signs. You can switch `\w` with `[A-Z]` if necessary.
If your 3 word phrase has to have 2 words with capital letters, change the second brackets to `([A-Z]\w* [a-z]+ [A-Z]\w*)`. Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/E3IPTj/1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the scope of your limitations but a few 'building blocks' might help. Also id suggest just starting at the beginning I don't know any recent websites that handle learning regex well but when I started I used the following http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html (It's been many years, and the website does reflect its age so to speak)

#### However onto your regex:

Following your example: `Institute of Technology`

You need to know just a few things, character sets (and how to use matching length) and the space.

Character sets match one length (by default) and are done like for example `[abc]` that will match a, b, or c, and also supports character ranges (a-z)/grouped (eg. \d all digits).
The match length can be changed by using the:

- `+` - one or more (examples: a+, [abc]+, \d+)
- `*` - zero or more (examples: a*, [abc]*)

And this one you might want but thats up to you

- `{min, max}` - specific range, eg. b{3,5} will match 3-5 joined 'b' characters (bbb, bbbb, bbbbb) max can be omitted `{min,} to have at least min chars but no max

Spaces are done using "" (a space), (`\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`) (spaces, tabs, newlines, ...)

In your example its a matter of case sensitive or not **if not case sensitive** we can use a simple `[A-Za-z]+` to match upper and lowercase a-z of at least one length, together with the space we get something along the lines of

```
/[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+/
```

It's that simple. For case insensitive matching there is also an option flag, we can use `i` which will result in

```
/[a-z]+ [a-z]+ [a-z]+/i
```

If you do want to **have case sensitive** matching you will need to separate them how you like:

```
/[A-Z][a-z]* [a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]*/ // (*A a A*)
```

As a small change I've also changed `+` into `*` so the lowercase part is not required, again up to you.

Also note that to match the beginning of a string your required to use `^` and to match the end of a string use `$` the above examples will match any segment, not the whole input eg: `qhg8Institute of Technology8tghagus` would work

#### So final result:

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]* [a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]*$/ // case sensitive (Aa a Aa)
/^[a-z]+ [a-z]+ [a-z]+$/i          // case insensitive
```

Obviously there is lots more to learn that can be used to expand/ optimize this but regex are so customizable its really up to the person needing them to specify his/ her limitations/ requirements.

---

As a side note I noticed people using `\w` for word chars, but this also includes digits, _, and special language letters like à, ü, etc. Again up to you what to do with this.